# find: invalid predicate `-L' error occurred while running Gatling simulation using git command prompt on windows machine

Tags: git, scala, gatling

Getting error while try run Gatling simulation using git command prompt.
User@VI-D054 /e/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.1.3/bin
$ sh gatling.sh
GATLING_HOME is set to /e/gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.1.3
find: invalid predicate `-L'
Choose a simulation number:
     [0] Simulation_one
     [1] Simulation_two
$ sh gatling.sh

Note :- Batch command is running fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you edit the line with :

```
COMPILATION_CLASSPATH=`find -L $GATLING_HOME/lib -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jar" -type f -exec printf :{} ';'`
```

to remove the `-L` option after `find`, it should work.
Still, the `-L` flag for `find` is not exactly specific…
It looks that the people that implemented `find` on that bash port forgot to implement it...

However, since you're obviously using Windows, why don't you use the `gatling.bat` script that Gatling provides ?